# Laravel's registration saves password incorrectly

Tags: laravel, authentication

I'm using `Laravel 5.5` and I have modified the registration process recently. This is the registration:

```
$user =  User::create([
            'gender' => $data['gender'],
            'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
            'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'status' => 'inactive',
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password'])
        ]);
```

which works fine so far. However, when I try to log in with the account I recently had created, it'd always tell me that was the wrong password and I don't understand why. I'm not exactly sure whether it was `Hash::make()` or `bcrypt()` originally and since they're different, I suppose there must be something wrong with the login.

If I `bcrypt` a password using `Tinker` and insert it into the DB, I'm able to login. I thought of modifying the "login code", however, I wouldn't find anything similiar to the registration looking process which would let me alter the used hash algorithm for login, so what's the approach in this case?

Edit: I placed this code above the `$user = User::create([])`:

```
dd($data['password'], bcrypt($data['password']), Hash::make($data['password']));
```

and this is the output:

> "testtesttest123456"
>
> "$2y$10$y9bl5muW5AmmMZMMEWL0Qucy7RSfCSzgWXl29PiX2gPRFd3jnNeEC"
>
> "$2y$10$tez1W8fIwpksgpjsZmQqPuYIN4QTtiddhaCnc5zQ2MgeYATiQd9Ym"

The user model (as per request):

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, HasRoles;

    const STATE_ACTIVE   = 'active';
    const STATE_INACTIVE = 'inactive';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password', 'status', 'profile_pic', 'api_token', 'activation_code'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
    {
        $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password);
    }

    public function setEmailAttribute($email)
    {
        $this->attributes['email'] = strtolower($email);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried replacing hash make with bycrypt?

Comment: Use `'password' => bcrypt($data['password'])` and then try to login!

Comment: did you only modify that method for creating the user, or did you also lets say add anything to the User model?

Comment: `bcrypt()` is just a shortcut for `Hash::make()`

Comment: @SapneshNaik yes, @ Hiren Gohel doesn't work (tried it), @ lagbox User model altered, @ Alexey Mezenin this is what I had in my mind, too, but different outputs speak a different language.

Comment: and what did you alter on the user model?

Comment: @Core-i9 what exactly do you mean by different output?

Comment: @lagbox I added the attributes `first_name`, `last_name` and so on.

Comment: just provide the model ... and every time you hash something it will be different, that is how this hashing works, so of course the multiple calls to the hasher will have different results

Comment: @lagbox thanks but I don't need an explanation on how hashs work since I very well know this, and I have never acted in counter of this.

Comment: @Core-i9 i was referring to the "different outputs" comment of yours

Answer (score 2):

You are double hashing the password. You have a mutator that is hashing the password. You are also hashing the password before passing it to `create`.

You have the choice of removing that mutator or not hashing the password before assigning it to the model (as assigning it causes the mutator to run). Either one is fine you just have to know which way you are going.

Most likely there is only going to be 2 places a password is getting hashed anyway, so its really not that big of a concern which way you go.

Registration and perhaps a change password/profile type route are basically the only places you will be hashing the password.

Comment: Okay. But how to tackle this?

Comment: you have to decide where you want the hashing to happen, as it can't happen in both places ... if you have the mutator you have to remember you have it, to not be assigning a hashed value to the model .. if you don't have the mutator you have to hash the value before assigning it

Comment: Now I see what you're after. Now, this is something I have not contributed there myself. Is it better to remove the hash inside the 'set' method or when creating the user?`

Comment: its up to you, its a preference (wont find a consensus) ... you just have to know these types of things exist or can exist on your models to avoid such issues down the road :)

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't done anything to the login/registration hasing in the controllers then this should work

```
$user =  User::create([
    'gender' => $data['gender'],
    'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
    'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'status' => 'inactive',
    'password' => bcrypt($data['password'])
]);
```